# Setting row specific content for a Combobox in a GridGroupingControl cell

Tags: winforms, combobox, syncfusion, gridgroupingcontrol

In my WinForms application, I have a GridGroupingControl where I need to display a certain data collection that has a rather complex structure.
The basic idea is that I want to have a combobox in one cell on each row, and that combobox has to contain a list that is defined for each row in the data collection.

Now my question is: How do I bind that specific list to the combobox in question?

My guess here is that I need to define this binding not on the column schema, but on the row schema in some way. How do I do this? I had guessed that I would add event handlers of the type "control.Row.DataBound" but I have not found any of the sort in this control.

NB: I come from a web development background, so my knowledge of Winforms is rather limited to begin with. Please bear that in mind when answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a combo box in grid, you need to set the celltype as `ComboBox` and the data for combobox using `ChoiceList`. Please refer the below provided code snippet and KB’s for further clarification. The below code can be directly used in `Form load` or `Constructor`. If you want to set a specific cell as combobox cell then you need to set the cell type of that particular cell in `QueryCellStyleInfo` event (refer the kb’s for this).

Code Snippet:

```
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[1].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.CellType= GridCellTypeName.ComboBox;
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[1].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.ChoiceList = list1;
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[1].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.CellValue = "Trial1";
```

KB links:

- [how-to-insert-a-combobox-in-a-header-cell-of-a-grid](http://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4121/how-to-insert-a-combobox-in-a-header-cell-of-a-grid)
- [how-to-change-the-dropdown-height-of-the-combobox-cell-dynamically](http://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4496/how-to-change-the-dropdown-height-of-the-combobox-cell-dynamically)

Comment: I've removed signatures in a pending edit, see the link for reasons. If you want to have an account clearly associated with Syncfusion support, you may use a disctinct name, image and profile info. http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior